# Exporting promethous metrics from log file using python client library

Tags: python, prometheus, python-3.7

There is a promethous client library to instrument python code to export promethous metrics for **scraping**. such as `Counter` , `Summary` , `Gauge`

But what is the best approach to use the same client library to export the metrics from an application that is not instrumented origionally, but the application log is available to get the metrics. Do we need to simulate the application behavior from the values in log file to export the metrics? or there is some other better approach to export the metrics from log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [grok exporter](https://github.com/fstab/grok_exporter) or [mtail](https://github.com/google/mtail) are usually used for this, rather than writing your own thing.